# Trying to find injection between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B, C$ be sets such that $f: A \to B $ is injective and $|B| = |C| $. prove there is an injection from $A$ to $C$.

Obviously, if we can find and injection $g: B \to C $ then the composition $g \circ f : A \to C $ would be the requires choice. So I was wondering that if we set $g(x) = x $ just identity then $g$ must be injective. but I feel as I am not using the fact that $|B| = |C| $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|B|=|C|$ means that there is a bijection, $g,$ from $B$ to $C$ so  $g \circ f$ is the injection you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know what $A,B,C$ and $f$ are, you can't just pick the identity function. So that doesn't quite work.

**HINT:** What does $|B|=|C|$ mean? It means that something exists. What?